# A stochastic volatility model

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

An example of stochastic volatility model:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dX_t}{X_t} &= g_t dW_t \\
 dg_t &= - k g_t dt + \sigma dZ_t
\end{cases}
$$

where $Z_t$  and $W_t$ are Brownian motions and  $dZ_t dW_t = 0$.

Want to ask if $X_T$ and $g_T$ are uncorrelated for $T>t$? 
i.e. $E_t\left[ X_T g_T  \right] = E_t\left[ X_T   \right]E_t\left[  g_T  \right] $ ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The processes $(X_t)_t$ and $(g_t)_t$ are driven by uncorrelated Brownian motions, so I guess those processes are uncorrelated as well. This is typically not the case for stochastic volatility models. Typically, in equity markets, $dZ_t dW_t = \rho <0$ to incorporate the leverage effect. Perhaps there is an analytical way to prove $\mathbb{E}[X_T g_T] = \mathbb{E}[X_T] \mathbb[g_T]$. However, solving such system of SDE's is not straightforward.

Comment: Actually this system of SDE can be solved in closed form for $X_t$ as long as you know the distribution of the cumulative squared volatility $\int_0^T g^2_u du$. 
$\\$ 
In any case here the two driving brownian motions $W_t$ and $Z_t$ of the single processes $X_t$ and $g_t$ are not correlated, but $X$ and $g$ are. You can see that by solving the first equation for an expression for $X_t$.